Why navigation cannot function properly after changing NavigationView to NavigationStack?
After switching from NavigationView to NavigationStack, clicking 'Edit' in the DetailView does not work as expected.
However, the page navigates normally when @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss in DetailView is removed.

ContentView.swift
struct ContentView: View {
  var body: some View {
    NavigationStack {
      NavigationLink("Detail") {
        DetailView()
      }
      .buttonStyle(.bordered)
      NavigationLink("About") {
        AboutView()
      }
      .buttonStyle(.bordered)
    }
    .navigationTitle("Home Page")
  }
}

DetailView.swift
struct DetailView: View {
  @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
  @State var info: String = "Hello"
  
  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      Text(info)
      HStack {
        // Need a button to trigger and return to the previous page
        Button("Back") {
          dismiss()
        }
        .buttonStyle(.bordered)
        
        // Why can't I navigate to the Edit page?
        NavigationLink("Edit") {
          EditView() { data in
            info = data
          }
        }
        .buttonStyle(.bordered)
      }
    }
    .navigationTitle("Detail Page")
  }
}

EditView.swift
struct EditView: View {
  @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
  let action: (String) -> Void
  
  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      Button("Save") {
        action("Hello World.") // Need to return some information.
        dismiss()
      }
      .buttonStyle(.bordered)
    }
    .navigationTitle("Edit Page")
  }
}

AboutView.swift
struct AboutView: View {
  @State private var isPresentWebView = false
  
  var body: some View {
    Button("Show website") {
      isPresentWebView = true
    }
    .buttonStyle(.bordered)
    .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $isPresentWebView) {
      SafariWebView(url: URL(string: "https://stackoverflow.com")!)
        .ignoresSafeArea()
    }
  }
}

struct SafariWebView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
  let url: URL
  
  func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> SFSafariViewController {
    return SFSafariViewController(url: url)
  }
  
  func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: SFSafariViewController, context: Context) {
    
  }
}


It works fine for me when I try your example code on an iPhone 15 simulator running iOS 17.5 (Xcode 15.4). What environment are you running on? Are you using a preview? The only thing I would suggest is that you might want to use a VStack as the container for the top-level NavigationLink inside the NavigationStack.

I am running in the iOS 17.4 (Xcode 15.3) environment and it cannot navigate properly. Later, I discovered that by changing the "@Environment(.dismiss) var dismiss" in "DetailView" to "@Environment(.presentationMode) var presentationMode", all functions can work together. I don't understand why or what problem caused this situation. Thank you for your answer.
